# php Withdrawal code not working

Tags: php

I have a personal project that needs fixing, please. The code below is supposed to withdraw an amount from workers account (debit the account) but it returns a blank space and displays an error. please i need assistance with the error or miss step as the case maybe. i am very new to php
here is my code

```
// connect db   
<?php
$username="root";
$server="localhost";
$dbname="workers_db";
$password="worded";
    $conn=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("SERVER ERROR".mysql_error());
?>

// check
<?php
if(isset($_GET['withdraw']))
{

$Req="SELECT * FROM balance";
$query=mysql_query($Req);
$nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
//echo $nums['CurrentB'];
$amount=$_GET['amount'];
$newB= ceil($nums['CurrentB']- $amount);
///////////////
if($newB>5000)
{

$amount=$_GET['amount'];
$withdrawal="UPDATE balance SET CurrentB=$newB,LastWithdraw=$amount,date=now() WHERE b_id=1; ";
$query2=mysql_query($withdrawal);
//$nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
    if($query2)
    {
    $Req="SELECT * FROM balance";
    $query=mysql_query($Req);
    $nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "Your new current account balance is". '  '.$nums['CurrentB'];
    echo "<br/>Your Last Withdrawal was ". '  '.$nums['LastWithdraw'];
    echo "<br/>Your Last Withdrawal Date was  on". '  '.$nums['date'];
    }
}
else
{
echo 'INSUFFICIENT BALANCE TO CONTINUE THIS TRANSACTION';
}
///////////////
}
else
{
$Req="SELECT * FROM balance";
$query=mysql_query($Req);
$nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo "Your current account balance is". '  '.$nums['CurrentB'];
}
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_GET['withdraw']))
{
?>
//the form
<form action="<?php  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Amount to Withdraw: &emsp;<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="Submit" name="withdraw" value="Proceed">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
//end
<br/><a href="index.php">EXIT</a>
```

Comment: what is the error that is displayed?

Comment: This is what is displayed "INSUFFICIENT BALANCE TO CONTINUE THIS TRANSACTION". It is expected to show that if the account =< 5000.

Comment: @Alex the content include b_id, CurrentB,Withdraw,date

Comment: Thank you @Alex. I found anoda way round it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, made some changes to your code, added inline comments, I hope it helps

```
<?php

$username="root";
$server="localhost";
$dbname="workers_db";
$password="worded";
$conn=mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("SERVER ERROR".mysql_error());


if(isset($_GET['withdraw'])) {

    $Req="SELECT * FROM balance"; // maybe you should you add a WHERE clause here
    $query=mysql_query($Req);
    $nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // what is the initial balance for this user? uncomment the line below and check the the numbers
    // echo $nums['CurrentB'];

    $amount=$_GET['amount'];
    $currentBalance = $nums['CurrentB'];
    $newBalance = ceil($currentBalance - $amount);

    // what is the newBalance for this user? uncomment the line below and see
    // print $newBalance;

    // if the balance after withdrawal is more the 5000 proceed
    if($newBalance > 5000) {
        $amount=$_GET['amount'];
        $withdrawal="UPDATE balance SET CurrentB=$newB,LastWithdraw=$amount,date=now() WHERE b_id=1; ";
        $query2=mysql_query($withdrawal);
        //$nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
        if($query2) {
        $Req="SELECT * FROM balance";
            $query=mysql_query($Req);
            $nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            echo "Your new current account balance is". '  '.$nums['CurrentB'];
            echo "<br/>Your Last Withdrawal was ". '  '.$nums['LastWithdraw'];
            echo "<br/>Your Last Withdrawal Date was  on". '  '.$nums['date'];
        }
    }
    // else give out error message
    else {
        echo 'INSUFFICIENT BALANCE TO CONTINUE THIS TRANSACTION';
    }

}
else {

    $Req="SELECT * FROM balance"; // maybe you should add here a WHERE clause, ex. WHERE b_id=xx
    $query=mysql_query($Req);
    $nums=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "Your current account balance is". '  '.$nums['CurrentB'];

    echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Amount to Withdraw: &emsp;<input type="text" name="amount">
    <input type="Submit" name="withdraw" value="Proceed">
    </form>';
    echo '<br/><a href="index.php">EXIT</a>';
}
?>
```

---

If you want to check for available balance to make a withdrawal,
test if the current balance is strictly smaller than the amount to be withdrawn and if true trigger an error message.

If the current balance is bigger or equal, meaning that the remaining balance will be zero, you can process the withdrawal.

```
if ($nums['CurrentB']<$amount) echo "not enough money";
else {
    // process the withdrawal
}
```

The test that you are doing is checking if the remaining balance is bigger than 5000, if true, process the balance, if false give out an error.

You can of course include this mandatory remaining balance, but in your test you need to check that the initial balance is well above the 5000 minimum.
Example:

```
if ($nums['CurrentB'] - $amount < 5000 ) echo "limit exceeded";
else {
    // process the withdrawal
}
```

Just make sure you make the difference between initial balance and remaining balance.

Comment: i can edit your full code but how do you want to proceed? do you need a minimum 5000 reserve ?

Comment: what are the contents of your balance table?

Comment: post here, so I can see